# Probability of drawing 2 certain cards out of 50 cards deck, and if dividing the deck into piles matters?

Tags: probability

this probability problem caused a heated discussion at work (what makes it funny is that non of us really have a mathematical background) and I really want a definitive answer:

**Q: assume you have 50 card deck containing 48 black cards and 2 red cards (the deck is then shuffled), and you are allowed to pick any 12 cards from the deck. which of the following methods will grant the biggest chance of you picking up a red card?**

1 - picking the first 12 cards from the top of the deck.

2- dividing the deck into 4 piles (say for example [12, 12, 12, 14]), and picking the top 3 cards of each pile.

Comment: The chances are identical. This is "obvious"; perhaps you'll get a better answer if you explain why anyone at your work thought the chances were *not* identical.

Comment: @MeesdeVries: perhaps someone told them about Monty Hall problem, but they didn't understand that it is the revealing of the box content (i.e. giving the user additional information) that changed the odds, not reshuffling the data